# img not showing up in styled components reactjs

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm using styled components.

component_name.js

```
// import statement
import MyArrow from '../../path/to/img.svg"; // <- svg file

// inside return statement
<Arrow src={MyArrow} />
```

styled.js

```
export const Arrow: Object = styled('img')`
  top: 5px;
  /* other styles ... */
`;
```

Image path is correct. But image is not showing up. HTML `img` is showing up in the DOM, but not include `src` attribute.

### Edit

I've updated to the styled.js like below.

```
export const Arrow: Object = styled('img')`
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  right: 4px;
  width: auto;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url(${(props) => props.src});
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
`;
```

Still not working. Got this error `Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string`.

Comment: create a codesandbox for your case. See if it works in code sandbox and we will help you from there

Answer (score 0):

Please try by adding the following properties

```
    width: auto;
    height: 500px;
    background-image:  
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
```

Comment: updated the question as your suggestion.

Comment: Are you trying to render a svg file ?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: If you are using WebPack you need to add file-loader for SVG

Comment: Yes. I'm using webpack.

Comment: Have you add file-loader ?

Comment: https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/

Comment: Added. Still not working.

Comment: can you try to use  const Div = styled.div`
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(${props => props.background});
` instead of img

Comment: Make sure props.src has a correct value